# is there a way to join some data from different tables into a query in mssql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables am working with. A stock_In Table and a Purchase_Return table.

```
 Stock in

Invoice No | Product Code | Price | Quantity | Amount | Discount | Total Amount
 In-0001   | PR-0001      | 900   | 30       |22500   |0.00      |22500
 In-0001   | PR-0002      | 250   | 30       |12500   |0.00      |12500
 In-0002   | PR-0003      | 350   | 30       |10500   |1050      |9450
 In-0002   | Pr-0004      | 400   | 5        |2000    |0.00      |2000

Purchase Return

Invoice No | Product Code | Price | Quantity | Amount | Discount |Total Amount
 In-0001   | PR-0004      | 400   | 2        |800     |0.00      |800
```

Now, this is what i want to have when have executed the query, Firstly, Stock In table has to check if Invoice No is available in Purchase Return. If yes, then i want to have the result below

```
Invoice No | Product Code | Price | Quantity | Amount | Discount | Total Amount
 In-0001   | PR-0001      | 900   | 30       |22500   |0.00      |22500
 In-0001   | PR-0002      | 250   | 30       |12500   |0.00      |12500
 In-0002   | PR-0003      | 350   | 30       |10500   |1050      |9450
 In-0002   | Pr-0004      | 400   | 2        |800     |0.00      |800
```

If no then i want to have the result below

```
Invoice No | Product Code | Price | Quantity | Amount | Discount | Total Amount
 In-0001   | PR-0001      | 900   | 30       |22500   |0.00      |22500
 In-0001   | PR-0002      | 250   | 30       |12500   |0.00      |12500
 In-0002   | PR-0003      | 350   | 30       |10500   |1050      |9450
 In-0002   | Pr-0004      | 400   | 5        |2000    |0.00      |2000
```

so what query do i need to write to achieve this, have tried numerous query but am still not getting it
Few of what have wrote is this

```
if exists (select Stock_In.Invoice_No from Stock_In,Purchase_Return where Stock_In.Invoice_No = Purchase_Return.Invoice_No)
begin
SELECT distinct Stock_In.Invoice_No,  stock_in.Product_Code, Stock_In.Price, 
        Stock_In.Quantity, Purchase_Return.Amount, Purchase_Return.Discount_Amount, Purchase_Return.Total_Amount
        FROM  Stock_In full outer join Purchase_Return on  Purchase_Return.Invoice_No =  Stock_in.Invoice_No 
End
else
begin
SELECT distinct Stock_In.Invoice_No,  stock_in.Product_Code, Stock_In.Price, 
       Stock_In.Quantity, Purchase_Return.Amount, Purchase_Return.Discount_Amount, Purchase_Return.Total_Amount
       FROM  Stock_In full outer join Purchase_Return on  Purchase_Return.Invoice_No =  Stock_in.Invoice_No 
end
```

This is the result of the query above

```
Invoice No | Product Code | Price | Quantity | Amount | Discount | Total_Amount
In-0001      PR-0001        900     25          Null     Null       NUll
IN-0001      PR-0002        250     50          Null     Null       NUll
IN-0002      PR-0003        350     30          2000     0.00       800
IN-0002      PR-0004        400     2           2000     0.00       800
```

Can anyone tell me what am missing from the query above

Comment: mysql does not have full join and the published code would have to be in a stored program- so are you looking for a sqlserver solution or a mysql solution or a dialect agnostic solution?

Comment: am looking for an sql server solution if available

Comment: Your first result seems wrong - there is no in-0001/pr-0004 in stock in and what if the purchase return price differs from stock in price?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not just after a `LEFT JOIn` and an `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`?

```sql
SELECT InvoiceNo,
       ProductCode,
       Price,
       ISNULL(PR.Quantity,SI.Quantity) AS Quanity,
       ISNULL(PR.Amount,SI.mount) AS Amount,
       ISNULL(PR.Discount,SI.Discount) AS Discount,
       ISNULL(PR.TotalAmount,SI.TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount
FROM dbo.StockIn SI
     LEFT JOIN dbo.PurchaseReturn PR ON SI.ProductCode = PR.ProductCode;
```

Comment: @Lamu Am still having duplicate value just like the result above

Comment: There is no `m` in my alias, @Temitayo  (or is that Ternitayo ?)

Comment: The above, with the sample data you have given us, won't produce additional rows, @Temitayo , as `PurchaseReturn` only has 1 row.

Comment: Please look close to PR003 and PR-0004, those are the two things am having problem with, I don't wanna add where product code clause to avoid giving me 1 row

Answer (score 0):

You can you SQL Joins to get the results that you want.

Comment: Please kindly drop your query

Comment: For an answer to be accepted, it is advisable to include examples, often relevant examples to the questions examples.

I would also recommend linking to documentation, and possibly quoting exerts from the documentation.

Comment: It also seems the asker has successfully used joins, but may have made mistakes on the type of join, and is using a function instead of a simple query (or view).

I would hazard a guess that they actually just want help picking and choosing the fields to output. If in doubt, comment on the question and ask for more information.